# How to make multiple shapes appear on the same screen?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm writing a program that allows the user to draw different shapes through the menu options, the shapes after being drawn need to be on the same screen, but the problem is that after choosing another option in the menu to draw another shape, the previous shape disappears. How can I fix this? This is my program:

```
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (shape == 1)
    {
        draw_rectangle();
    }

    if (shape == 2)
    {
        draw_circle();
    }

    glFlush();
}

void menu(int choice)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        shape = 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        shape = 2;
        break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

The `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` is only in `display()`.

Comment: Depending on how your shapes look (and of course if they don't move), you might get away with just not clearing the buffer upon redraws (meaning: just drawing on top of your previous image). However that's an ugly solution and has several issues like not being able to react to window size changes. Better would probably be to create a list of shapes to be drawn and just to draw all shapes in that list every time your window gets redrawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a separate Boolean state variables for each shape (`rectangle_shape`, `circle_shape`), instead of one integral variable that indicates the shape (`shape`):

```cpp
bool rectangle_shape = false;
bool circle_shape = false;

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (rectangle_shape)
    {
        draw_rectangle();
    }

    if (circle_shape)
    {
        draw_circle();
    }

    glFlush();
}

void menu(int choice)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        rectangle_shape = !rectangle_shape;
        break;
    case 2:
        circle_shape = !circle_shape;
        break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```